# Euler angles and extrude direction

Tags: c++

I'm creating a C++ ifc importer.

I have a direction vector and I want to extrude a section from it. The section itself is a list of 2d points.
To calculate the extrusion direction I have to multiply a non-transformed direction with a transformation matrix.

The matrix has a transformation in `x`, `y`, and `z` (like Euler angles).

I must calculate the rotation angle around the extrude direction.

I have a matrix class that returns the Euler angles from a 
matrix:

`matrix.ExtractEulerXYZ(x,y,z)`

The problem is that I can have a direction vector that has a rotation in `x`, `y` or `z`, how can I select the correct angle `x`, `y`, or `z` from the extrude direction?

Comment: are you doing 3d math of 2d vectors? this is not advised. at the very least have all points generated as <x, y, 0>, or <x, 0, z>, but beyond that are you trying to identify these angles, or simply do the conversion on the points? also why not just do vector addition? you might also want to think of other tags. as this seems non language specific, and is more of a general [math] thing

Answer (score 0):

A 2d point is at location (x, y) in 2d space and (x, y, 0) in 3d space.

Euler angles in 3d space define 3 rotations from the xyz axes to rotate the xyz axes to the specified point. That is, if you mark a point on the x axis that is the correct distance on the x axis to the point, you rotate the axes by a along the XY plane, b along the ZY plane and c along the ZX plane.

See the animation in the "Relationship with physical motions" section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles -- particularly, follow the progress of the x axis that initially projects toward the bottom left corner.

If you just have a 2d point, the ZY and ZX rotations do not do anything -- you are just rotating around the XY axis. Therefore, you can use simple trigonometry (SOH CAH TOA) to find the angle of the line from the origin to the point; there is no need to use a matrix.